# Press any key in 5 seconds

Tags: events, time, lua, wait, computercraft

To clarify, I am using ComputerCraft (emulator: http://gravlann.github.io/, language: Lua)

I know that to wait for a keypress

```
os.pullEvent("key")
```

and to wait 5 seconds I need to use this

```
sleep(5)
```

but I want to wait for a keypress and disable the event waiter after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with *ComputerCraft API*, but I guess, You could use [`parallel API`](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Parallel_%28API%29) for this. Basically, it allows executing two or more functions in parallel.

To be specific - [`parallel.waitForAny`](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Parallel.waitForAny). Which returns after **any** of function finished, so, only the one being executed. In contrary, [`parallel.waitForAll`](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Parallel.waitForAll)  waits for all functions being executed.

I'd use something like this:

```
local action_done = 0

local function wait_for_keypress()
    local event, key_code = os.pullEvent("key")

    --do something according to separate key codes? :}
end

local function wait_some_time()
    sleep(5)
end

action_done = parallel.waitForAny(wait_for_keypress, wait_some_time)
--action done now contains the number of function which was finished first.
```

**EDIT:** if using only *ComputerCraft API*, You should change to this (using [`timer event`](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Timer_%28event%29)):

```
local function wait_some_time()
    os.startTimer(5)
end
```